# Inter-network communications

Tags: networking, ip, packet

I have an internet connection at my residence through my cable provider. Obviously it hooks into my cable modem which them hooks into my router where the signal is switched to the wireless access point and transmitted to my desktop.

If I wanted to communicate to another device on my network, wired or otherwise, I'd use the IP of the network chip on board that device, and the switch would take care of the difference. If I wanted to connect to a server on the internet, I'd use the public IP of the modem that server is communicating through - or more likely, the place holder text that gets converted to that IP.

But what if I wanted to communicate across modems (from the one I own to say, one at my place of employment, or to my neighbors modem down the road), to a specific device in a group of devices communicating to their service provider through a single modem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your internal network device's to be able to talk to another distinctly separate network's internal devices across the public internet, you most likely need a VPN connection of some sort... either a soft client on your PC to a VPN server on the remote end or a hardware VPN (router to router), this would give you network access to devices on the remote network.

Depending on your application, you may be able to use something like TeamViewer to take control of a remote machine to do what you need as well, it is generally less difficult to implement but make sure to check with the administrator for the remote network on their security policies.

Comment: Although you can do some of this on your own, be aware that if you are connecting to a corporate network this can have massive security implications. Always check with your corporate IT department if this is the situation. Doing this yourself between two private (individual) networks can be accomplished with things like OpenVPN or Logmein Hamachi, also be aware that some home routers, such as Asus, have a built in VPN client for remote access to the network.

Comment: Thank you acejavelin. I will heed your warning regarding corporate security. I wonder though, is it not possible to communicate like this through command line -what if I were dealing with a couple of terminals? Is there no way to send a packet out towards a modem with an internal address qualifier stored inside, whereupon it would be redirected to the internal device. Or is this essentially what you are talking about when you say "VPN"?

Comment: A VPN is a Virtual Private Network, it builds a secure tunnel for data between two networks which is exactly what you are looking for. Two distinctly different internal LANs cannot really talk to each other in any way. If you need a simple service, like RDP or https, you can often do port forwarding on the firewall of the remote end to access those limited services, but a VPN is preferred due to security issues